# query on super class and inherited class

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Having two classes, which I both use, I want to query the following:

- all entries from MyClass with value let's say equal 1
- all entries from BaseClass which do not originate from entries in MyClass

The dummy classes are as follows:

```
Base = declarative_base()                                     

class BaseClass(Base):                                        

    __tablename__ = 'base'                                    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                    
    value = Column(String(256), nullable=False)               
    type = Column(String(40))                                 

    __mapper_args__ = {                                       
        'polymorphic_identity': 'base',                       
        'polymorphic_on': type                                
        }                                                     


class MyClass(BaseClass):                                     
    __tablename__ = 'mine'                                    

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('qg.id'), nullable=False, 
        primary_key=True)                                     
    data = Column(Integer, nullable=False)                    

    __mapper_args__ = {                                       
        'polymorphic_identity': 'mine'                        
        }
```

Thanks for any hint (best for sqlalchemy, mysql query would also be fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that helped me:

with mySQL

```
SELECT value FROM base LEFT JOIN mine ON mine.id = base.id WHERE base.type = 'base' OR mine.data = 1;
```

or using sqlalchemy

```
q = session.query(Base)                      
q = q.outerjoin(Mine)                          
q = q.filter(                                                           
    or_(Base.type == 'Base',                         
        Mine.id == 1))                         
result = q.all()
```